# How to find the remainder of ${289 \times 144^{25}}$ divided by ${71^{71}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am solving this question.

Finding the remainder of

$$\frac{289\times 144^{25}}{71^{71}}$$

This is how I have tried solving it. First it can be simplified to $\frac{17^2 \times 2 ^{50} \times 3^{25}}{71^{71}}$. Now if we use Euler Totient rule we get for $\phi(71^{71}) = 71(1-\frac{1}{71}) = 70 $.

For,
$$ \frac{a^{\phi(n)}}{n}$$

I would get remainder as $1$.

I can't proceed from this point. Can someone help me to find out the remainder and where I went wrong?

EDIT : My totient rule was wrong. It's  $\phi(71^{71}) = 71^{71}(1-\frac{1}{71}) = 71^{70} \times 70 $.

EDIT #2 :  tried solving this in a different way.

$$ \frac{289}{71} \times \frac{144^{25}}{71^{70}}$$

For the first separated division we get $289 \equiv 5 \bmod 71$. Now further simplifying the second,
$$\frac{12^{50}}{71^{70}} = \left( \frac{12^5}{71^7} \right)^{10} = \left( \frac{12}{71} \right)^{70} \times \frac{1}{12^{20}}$$

Now I get $12 \equiv -59 \bmod 71$. 
I'm stuck again here.

Comment: Your Totient formula use is off. For a prime power $p^k$ it should be $p^k(1-1/p)=p^k-p^{k-1}.$ However how does that help in doing the problem?

Comment: $$\phi(71^{71})= = 71^{71}(1-\frac{1}{71}) = 70 \cdot 71^{70}$$Use Hansel Lemma

Comment: The numerator is smaller than the denominator, so you (just) have to compute the numerator and you can call it a day (or a month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

${289 \times 144^{25}} \approx 2.6 \times 10^{56} <  2.8 \times 10^{131}  \approx 71^{71}$. 
So the remainder is ${289 \times 144^{25}}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$17^2 12^{25} 12^{25} = 17^2 4^{25} 36^{25} = 16\cdot 17^2 4^{23} 36^{25} < 71\cdot 71^2 71^{23} 71^{25}$

Comment: Should that be $17^2 12^{25} 12^{25}$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: I didn't understand the hint properly. 
Also I tried solving this way, $ 289 ≡ 5 $ mod $71$ $ and $ 144 ≡ -2 $ mod $ 71$

Comment: @sudoankit: $x \bmod y = x $ whenever $0\le x <y$.